# Iterate through an object which has nested objects in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, underscore.js

I have a javascript object with multiple nested objects like this :

```
 var stats = {
     bookServed: {
         redis: 90,
         s3: 90,
         signedUrl: 70
     },
     errors: {
         redis: {
             bookService: 70,
             mapi: 50,
             capi: 30
         },
         AWS: {
             signedUrl: 70,
             downloadBook: 50,
             searchBook: 10
         },
         decryption: 60
     }
 };
```

What would be the cleanest way to iterate through all its properties and set each value to `0` for instance. I wrote something like this

```
 for (var property in stats) {
     if (stats.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
         if (typeof property === "object") {
             for (var sub_property in property)
                 if (property.hasOwnProperty(sub_property)) {
                     sub_property = 0
                 }
         } else {
             property = 0;
         }
     }
 }
```

I'm willing to use a library like underscore.js to do the task properly.

Comment: Any library you use is going to use a similar method of recursive looping. I assume what you have works, and you're just looking for something... "cleaner" *(whatever that means)*?

Comment: My solution works only for 2 levels of nested objects, in my example I have 3 level, that's why I want something recursive that go to the deepest level no matter how many levels I have in my object.

Comment: so make a function that does the step, and if an object is found instead of a number, call the function again on the sub object.

Comment: Ok I got the idea, but how to make it recursive?

Comment: *"and if an object is found instead of a number, call the function again on the sub object."* that would make it recursive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Relatively simple recursion problem, I would use a function that calls itself when sub objects are found. I would also avoid using a for in loop, and instead use a forEach on the object's keys (it's much faster, and doesn't require a hasOwnProperty check.)

```js
function resetValuesToZero (obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            return resetValuesToZero(obj[key]);
        }
        obj[key] = 0;
    });
}

var stats = {
     bookServed: {
         redis: 90,
         s3: 90,
         signedUrl: 70
     },
     errors: {
         redis: {
             bookService: 70,
             mapi: 50,
             capi: 30
         },
         AWS: {
             signedUrl: 70,
             downloadBook: 50,
             searchBook: 10
         },
         decryption: 60
     }
 };

console.log(stats.errors.AWS.signedUrl); // 70
resetValuesToZero(stats);
console.log(stats.errors.AWS.signedUrl); // 0
```

Comment: Note that if the object is extremely deeply nested, this could throw a stack overflow exception, but I'd consider that to be very much an edge case. To overcome that, you would need to make this function asynchronous, but I wouldn't bother with that unless you actually ran into that problem, as it definitely complicates things a bit.

Comment: Posted an answer that uses the iterative approach rather than recursion. Also not that this answer will traverse into arrays (it is not clear from the question if that is intended).

Answer (score 1):

The below solution uses [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan), which uses an iterative implementation to traverse the input. Also note that this will traverse into any array structures similar to the accepted answer.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const rewriter = objectScan(['**'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ value, parent, property }) => {
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
      parent[property] = 0;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
});

const stats = { bookServed: { redis: 90, s3: 90, signedUrl: 70 }, errors: { redis: { bookService: 70, mapi: 50, capi: 30 }, AWS: { signedUrl: 70, downloadBook: 50, searchBook: 10 }, decryption: 60 } };

console.log(rewriter(stats)); // returns count of replaces
// => 10

console.log(stats);
/* =>
{ bookServed: { redis: 0, s3: 0, signedUrl: 0 },
  errors:
  { redis: { bookService: 0, mapi: 0, capi: 0 },
    AWS: { signedUrl: 0, downloadBook: 0, searchBook: 0 },
    decryption: 0 } }
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkNPE(obj) {
  for(const name in obj){console.log('name: ' + JSON.stringify(name, null, 4));
    if (typeof obj[name] === 'object') {console.log('object name: ' + JSON.stringify(name, null, 4));
      checkNPE(obj[name]);
    } // if (typeof obj[name] === 'object') {
  } // for(const name in obj){
}; // function checkNPE (obj) {

var stats = {
     bookServed: {
         redis: 90,
         s3: 90,
         signedUrl: 70
     },
     errors: {
         redis: {
             bookService: 70,
             mapi: 50,
             capi: 30
         },
         AWS: {
             signedUrl: 70,
             downloadBook: 'a',
             searchBook: 10
         },
         decryption: 60
     }
 };
checkNPE(stats);
```